# What does it mean ? ..an alternative to..?

Tags: meaning

All, I was reading a document talk about a computer science framework(dcm4chee).
https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Compression+Service

But I have problem to understand some sentence of it. Please help to review it .

What I have trouble to understand is the first sentence of the document.

> Compression Service. The Compression Service supports delayed,
>   lossless compression of received images. This is an alternative to
>   immediately compressing images when received.

I think it is because I didn't know the `an alternative to` meaning.

Does it mean the Compression Service only support delayed lossless compression of received images? I mean not support the immediately compressing images when received?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compression Service schedules compression of incoming images, so there will be some delay between receipt of an image and the storage of the compressed version of that image.  *An alternative to* means another way of doing things. In this case, the other way is immediately compressing each image as it arrives.

Comment: so , Can I say that Compression service Only support delayed compression? Thanks.

Comment: That's different from what the Compression Service documentation says.  It's possible that the parameters to the Service could be set so that the system is forced to compress images upon receipt.  I can't tell.

Comment: Yes . Sure it is . It is like what you said. It is just a delayed service. Actually .There exist another service to provide immediately compression. Thank you.